# Check if vector of bools (range) equals to sequence of 1 and 0

Tags: c++, vector

What I had before was a string of 1s and 0s and I could simply check whether some range equals to a sequence I wanted:

```
if (myString.substr(0, 4) == "1110") ...
```

For memory reasons, I've made this string into `vector<bool>`, since one bool in vector only takes 1 bit instead of 1 byte.

Now, here's a problem. I want to do same comparison as I did with `substr`. Possibly without anything like:

```
if(myVector[0] == true && myVector[1] == true && ...)
```

or

```
vector<bool> tmpVector;
tmpVector.push_back(true);
tmpVector.push_back(true);
...
if (myVector == tmpVector) ...
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Is `bool` a single byte really? Most boolean types I've seen are signed 16-bit integers.

Comment: TIL `std::vector<bool>` is backed by an array of bits :) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/

Comment: @DrewNoakes I'm glad my question wasn't absolutely useless. :)

Comment: @Mauren, it's a byte on every platform I use (but the standard doesn't guarantee that)

Comment: @JonathanWakely @DrewNoakes I just learned about `vector<bool>`. Nice thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool tmpVector[4] = {true, true, true, false};
if (std::equal(myVector.begin(), myVector.begin() + 4, tmpVector)) {
}
```

Comment: Would this be possible without allocating `tmpVector`?

Comment: @Saraph I don't see how 4 bytes on the stack is anything to worry about, this will even take one byte less than your previous array `"1110"` because of the terminating null-character.

Comment: @Saraph You need some type of source data to compare against and it has to be stored somewhere. Declare it `static const` if it's data you compare against often.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Will do that. Thanks.